# Error in Inserting csv records to mysql table in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, csv, import

I'm having problem on how can I insert the csv file to the selected table,I want to insert those csv records even the other columns are blank. 
I want to insert its records even its having duplicates
Here is my code:

```
            // If all fields are input; and file is correct .csv format; continue
        if(!empty($_POST['table_select']) && !empty($_POST['csv_file']) && ($ext === 'csv')) {

            // Grab all columns
            $db_cols = $wpdb->get_col( "DESC " . $_POST['table_select'], 0 );  // Array of db column names

            // Get the number of columns from the hidden input field (re-auto-populated via jquery)
            $numColumns = $_POST['num_cols'];

            // Open the .csv file and get it's contents
            if(( $fh = @fopen($_POST['csv_file'], 'r')) !== FALSE) {

                // Set variables
                $values = array();
                $too_many = '';  // Used to alert users if columns do not match

                while(( $row = fgetcsv($fh)) !== FALSE) {  // Get file contents and set up row array
                    if(count($row) == $numColumns) {  // If .csv column count matches db column count
                        $values[] = '("' . implode('", "', $row) . '")';  // Each new line of .csv file becomes an array
                    }
                }

                // Set the staring row number to 2(two) to prevent adding the column header titles of the csv file
                $num_var = '2'- 1;  // Subtract one to make counting easy on the non-techie folk!  (1 is actually 0 in binary)

                // // If user input number exceeds available .csv rows
                // if($num_var > count($values)) {
                //  $error_message .= '* '.__('Starting Row value exceeds the number of entries being updated to the database from the .csv file.','jwp_csv_2_db').'<br />';
                //  $too_many = 'true';  // set alert variable
                // }
                // // Else splice array and remove number (rows) user selected
                // else {
                    $values = array_slice($values, $num_var);
                // }

                // If the user DID NOT input more rows than are available from the .csv file
                if($too_many !== 'true') {

                    //$db_query_update = '';
                    $db_query_insert = '';

                    // Format $db_cols to a string
                    $db_cols_implode = implode(',', $db_cols);

                    // Format $values to a string
                    $values_implode = implode(',', $values);

                    // SQL Query to Insert the csv data to the databas table
                    $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$_POST['table_select'] . ' (' . $  . ') ' . 'VALUES ' . $values_implode;
                    $db_query_insert = $wpdb->query($sql);

                    // // If db db_query_update is successful
                    // if ($db_query_update) {
                    //  $success_message = __('Congratulations!  The database has been updated successfully.','jwp_csv_2_db');
                    // }
                    // // If db db_query_insert is successful
                    //elseif ($db_query_insert) {
                    if ($db_query_insert) {
                        $success_message = __('Congratulations!  The database has been updated successfully.','jwp_csv_2_db');
                        $success_message .= '<br /><strong>'.count($values).'</strong> '.__('record(s) were inserted into the', 'jwp_csv_2_db').' <strong>'.$_POST['table_select'].'</strong> '.__('database table.','jwp_csv_2_db');
                    }
                    // // If db db_query_insert is successful AND there were no rows to udpate
                    // elseif( ($db_query_update === 0) && ($db_query_insert === '') ) {
                    //  $message_info_style .= '* '.__('There were no rows to update. All .csv values already exist in the database.','jwp_csv_2_db').'<br />';
                    // }
                    else {
                        $error_message .= '* '.__('There was a problem with the database query.','jwp_csv_2_db').'<br />';
                        echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n";
                        $error_message .= '* '.__('A duplicate entry was found in the database for a .csv file entry.','jwp_csv_2_db').'<br />';
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                $error_message .= '* '.__('No valid .csv file was found at the specified url. Please check the "Select CSV File" field and ensure it points to a valid .csv file.','jwp_csv_2_db').'<br />';
            }
        }
```